# Using the Krylov method for Solve: Speeding up a SparseArray calculation

Tags: equation-solving, matrix, performance-tuning, linear-algebra, sparse-arrays

I'm trying to implement this [Total Variation Regularized Numerical Differentiation (TVDiff)](http://math.lanl.gov/~rick/Software/TVDiff/) code in *Mathematica* (which I found through [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6502440/numerical-differentiation-of-list-in-mathematica) answer): essentially, I want to differentiate noisy data. The full paper behind the idea is [available from LANL](http://math.lanl.gov/Research/Publications/Docs/chartrand-2007-numerical.pdf). For a related idea, see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation_denoising) Wikipedia article.

The **problem I am currently having is the very long time it takes to solve the `Solve` function**. The full TVD function is as follows:

```
TVD[data_, dx_] := 
 Module[{n, ep, c, DD, DDT, A, AT, u0, u, ATb, ofst, kernel, alph, ng,
    stopTol, d, iter, xs, i = 0, q, l, g, tol, maxit, p, time, s},
  n = Length@data;
  ep = 1 10^-6;
  c = Table[1/dx, {n + 1}];
  DD = SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}] -> -c, Band[{1, 2}] -> c}, {n, 
     n + 1}];
  DDT = DD\[Transpose];

  A[list_] := dx Drop[(Accumulate[list] - 1/2 (list + list[[1]])), 1] ;
  AT[list_] := 
   dx ( Total[list] Table[1, {n + 1}] - 
      Join[{Total[list]/2}, (Accumulate[list] - list/2)]);

  ofst = data[[1]];
  ATb = AT[ofst - data];

  kernel[m_] := 
   Join[{0}, Table[Exp[-1] BesselI[n, 1], {n, -m, m}], {0}]/
    Total[Join[{0}, Table[Exp[-1] BesselI[n, 1], {n, -m, m}], {0}]];

  u0 = Join[{0}, Differences[data], {0}];
  u = SparseArray[u0];

  alph = StandardDeviation@ListConvolve[kernel[2], data]/
    StandardDeviation[data];

  ng = Infinity;
  d = 0;
  stopTol = .05;

  iter = 100;
  xs = Table[Symbol["x" <> ToString@i], {i, n + 1}];
  For[i = 0, i < iter, i++,
   q = SparseArray[Band[{1, 1}] -> 1/Sqrt[(DD.u)^2 + ep], {n, n}];
   l = dx DDT.q.DD;
   g = AT[ A[ u ] ] + ATb + alph l.u;

   tol = 10^-4;
   maxit = 1;
   (* preconditioner *)
   p = alph SparseArray[Band[{1, 1}] -> Diagonal[l], {n + 1, n + 1}];
   time = 
    AbsoluteTiming[
     s = xs /. 
        First[Solve[Thread[alph l.xs + AT[ A[ xs ] ] == g], xs, 
          Method -> {"Krylov", Method -> "ConjugateGradient", 
            "Preconditioner" -> (p.# &), Tolerance -> tol, 
            MaxIterations -> maxit}]];];
   u = u - s;
   If[Norm[s]/Norm[u] < stopTol, Break[];];
   ];
  u
  ]
```

Note: lower the `stopTol` value to ensure a better resulting derivative.

For comparison, the MATLAB code (which I translated to *Mathematica*, and is available from the [first link](http://math.lanl.gov/~rick/Software/TVDiff/)) for the "solve" portion is as follows:

```
s = pcg( @(v) ( alph * L * v + AT( A( v ) ) ), g, tol, maxit, P )
```

Here, MATLAB defines the solver [`pcg`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pcg.html) as:

> `pcg(A, b, tol, maxit, M)` and `pcg(A, b, tol, maxit, M1, M2)` use symmetric positive definite preconditioner `M` or `M = M1*M2` and effectively solve the system `inv(M)*A*x = inv(M)*b` for `x`. If `M` is `[]` then `pcg` applies no preconditioner. `M` can be a function handle `mfun` such that `mfun(x)` returns `M\x`.

Note also that the `@(v)` is a 'pure function' in MATLAB terms, and is allowed as per:

> `A` can be a function handle `afun` such that `afun(x)` returns `A*x`.

When I run the two codes, MATLAB ends up being ~5-20 times faster than the corresponding *Mathematica* code. My *Mathematica* implementation of it uses more or less the entire CPU time on the `Solve` function.

I tried to find the best corresponding *Mathematica* Solver routine that matched the MATLAB description via [the docs](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v5_2/Built-inFunctions/AdvancedDocumentation/LinearAlgebra/LinearAlgebraInMathematica/MatrixComputations/SolvingLinearSystems/AdvancedDocumentationLinearAlgebra3.1.5.html) and [two](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2011/Nov/msg00754.html) [different](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2011/Dec/msg00020.html) MathGroup archived messages. None of the options (whether given with or without quotes) seem to help at all.

For testing purposes, here is some data:

```
data = {4699.1`, 4728.3`, 4753.3`, 4787.4`, 4794.8`, 4817.5`, 4842.7`,
   4877.2`, 4888.2`, 4916.1`, 4933.7`, 4951.5`, 4984.1`, 4984.2`, 
  5004.`, 5031.`, 5048.1`, 5062.3`, 5083.2`, 5096.`, 5108.5`, 5140.`, 
  5142.8`, 5142.7`, 5169.1`, 5168.6`, 5165.`, 5191.8`, 5193.7`, 
  5199.4`, 5189.3`, 5213.6`, 5209.1`, 5208.5`, 5197.`, 5201.2`, 
  5184.2`, 5191.2`, 5183.7`, 5181.3`, 5183.2`, 5175.6`, 5089.9`, 
  5068.1`, 5053.9`, 5056.7`, 5063.6`, 5038.2`, 5023.9`, 5027.4`, 
  4998.8`, 4980.9`, 4961.9`, 4939.3`, 4933.`, 4897.7`, 4879.`, 4874.`,
   4857.3`, 4819.2`, 4801.6`, 4775.5`, 4754.9`, 4712.2`, 4708.3`, 
  4675.8`, 4637.1`, 4634.1`, 4582.6`, 4558.3`, 4531.`, 4507.9`, 
  4470.4`, 4445.7`, 4435.`, 4404.3`, 4383.5`, 4363.7`}
```

You can make it bigger (which also coincidentally crashes my *Mathematica* if too big...) by:

```
data = Join[data, Reverse@data, data, Reverse@data, data, 
   Reverse@data, data];
```

(rinse & repeat as necessary). The data looks like:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And the function `TVD[data, 1/Length @ data]` looks like:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So, **how can I speed the solver up**? Is MATLAB just that much better at 'sparse array' type calculations? Did I not define the right `SparseArray`s? Is there a way to use `LinearSolve` when the matrix equation is not a simple `A.x` on the left hand side?

Any and all speed improvements would be great!

Comment: I haven't looked into this method and don't have time right now so I can't answer your question at the moment. However if you just want to differentiate noisy data and don't care about the approach, you can perhaps use the Savitzky-Golay method. I posted some code on MathGroup [here](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2012/Feb/msg00036.html).

Comment: @OleksandrR. Thanks for the link, I'll take a look!

Comment: @NasserM.Abbasi I asked that mostly rhetorically. While matrix things in matlab are generally easier to do than in MMA, I much prefer MMA's syntax / computational abilities. I'm really hoping that I'm just missing the right options and / or understanding of how to make my problem work with MMA's Solve / LinearSolve

Comment: @tkott, when I run your code I get messages :-( `SparseArray::bndtr:`

Comment: @ruebenko Actually, I should have mentioned that. That's just a warning because I set the size of a couple Sparse arrays to be smaller than the band I place a vector into. The SparseArray comes out fine, however.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I found a way to dramatically improve the performance of this algorithm by using the undocumented function `` SparseArray`KrylovLinearSolve ``. The key advantage of this function is that it seems to be a near-analog of MATLAB's `pcg`, and as such accepts as a first argument either:

> a square matrix, or a function generating a vector of length equal to the length of the second argument.

One may discover this by giving incorrect arguments and noting the advice given in the messages produced as a result, in much the same way as one discovers the correct arguments for any undocumented function. In this case the message is `` SparseArray`KrylovLinearSolve::krynfa ``.

You only need to change one line in your code to use it, namely:

```
s = SparseArray`KrylovLinearSolve[
     alph l.# + AT[A[#]] &, g, 
     Method -> "ConjugateGradient", "Preconditioner" -> (p.# &), 
     Tolerance -> tol, MaxIterations -> maxit
    ];
```

where `maxit` should preferably be `Automatic` (meaning 10 times the size of the system to be solved) or larger. With the data given in your question it takes a few hundred iterations to converge to a tolerance of $10^{-4}$, but each iteration is quite fast, so it seems to make more sense to adjust the tolerance than the number of iterations if performance is still an issue. However, while I didn't investigate this, needing this many iterations to converge to a relatively loose tolerance may of course be symptomatic of a poorly conditioned system, so using a different preconditioner or the biconjugate gradient stabilized method (`"BiCGSTAB"`) could perhaps reduce the number of iterations required.

You will note that the options are exactly the same as for `LinearSolve`'s `"Krylov"` method, so we may surmise that this function is probably called more or less directly by `LinearSolve` when `Method -> "Krylov"` is specified. In fact, if we assume that this is indeed the case and try

```
s = LinearSolve[
     alph l.# + AT[A[#]] &, g, 
     Method -> {"Krylov",
       Method -> "ConjugateGradient", "Preconditioner" -> (p.# &), 
       Tolerance -> tol, MaxIterations -> maxit
      }
    ];
```

we find that it works equally well, so evidently `LinearSolve` does in fact provide just the same functionality as `pcg` as far as the first argument is concerned, but without this actually being documented anywhere as far as I can tell. So, the overall conclusion is that you can just use `LinearSolve` directly after all.

Comment: Stupid undocumented functions. Thanks Oleksandr! I'll play around with this on Monday :)

Comment: Finally got around to checking this darned thing. Your solution of using LinearSolve + the pure function worked like a charm! Thanks

Answer (score 7):

This is not an answer, but may be it is :) as I do not have time to fully understand the question, just picked up few terms, but just in case, I thought I mention this.

Mathematica 8 already has Krylov method in LinearSolve ! so, if you are just looking to use these methods to solve Ax=b, it is already there.

Here is an example from my code (I used these in a demo for solving poisson 2D pde)

```
Which[preconditioner == "ILU0",
  x = LinearSolve[A, rightHandVector, 
    Method -> {"Krylov", Method -> nonStationarySolver, 
      "Preconditioner" -> preconditioner, MaxIterations -> Automatic, 
      Tolerance -> 10^-toleranceConstant}],
  True,
  x = LinearSolve[A, rightHandVector, 
    Method -> {"Krylov", Method -> nonStationarySolver, 
      "Preconditioner" -> {preconditioner, "FillIn" -> fillIn}, 
      MaxIterations -> Automatic, Tolerance -> 10^-toleranceConstant}]
  ];
```

In the above A is sparse 2D matrix and rightHandVector is the 'b' vector in Ax=b

There are many other submethods for Krylov and options  If this is what you are asking for, then you can check my demo for more example, I also implement Preconditioned Conjugate Gradients Method (what Matlab pcg does).

If this is NOT what you are asking for, I can delete this. (the comment was too small to write all this in).

ps. the code for this is here  http://12000.org/my_notes/mma_demos/poisson_2D/index.htm

Comment: I would love to use `LinearSolve`. however, my left hand side "matrix" is really: `l.x + AT[ A[ x ] ]` (i.e., it is not of a form `M.x==b`, but in some sense `f[M]==b`, where the functions `f` takes care of `M.x`. If there is a way to do make this work with MMA's `LinearSolve`, I'm all for it.

Comment: Simple question: where did you find the list of methods available for `LinearSolve`?

Comment: Difficult?!? I'd say it borders on impossible. Maybe it is in need of a question?

Comment: @rcollyer Actually I link to that discussion in my question :) (there are two links right before "MathGroup")