# Numerical Differentiation using 1500 data points

Tags: import, numerics

I have a set of 1500 data points (which are some energy eigenvalues) corresponding to a parameter H0 (which represents magnetic field. H0 values are equispaced going from $-3.0$ to $3.0$ in steps of $0.005$. Please note that the energy eigenvalues are not exact and they have experimental error in them. What I am trying to do is first plot those data points in *Mathematica*.

I have found the command `ListLinePlot[{{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, ...}]`. However, feeding such a huge set of data points consumes a lot of time. So is there any other way out? For example, importing the data file from Fortran. I have used the command `Import["file", "table"]` where "file" is a Fortran data file. But it is giving the error message "File not found during import".

Then I would like to find the second derivative of the plot. Accurate evaluation of second derivative is very crucial for my purpose. I have done the plot using "gnuplot" and then found the first derivative of the plot using the central difference formula: $\frac{f(x+h)-f(x-h)}{2h}$. Here $h = 0.005$. Then I evaluated the first derivative of the latter plot using the same formula to get the second derivative plot.

I am getting the plot but not the desired result (a peak is to be obtained near a value of H0, pre-calculated). In other words, I am getting a disagreement between theoretical and numerical values of H0. The eigenvalue evaluation is OK I think because I have checked it both in *Mathematica* and Fortran. Maybe something is going wrong in the second derivative evaluation. Kindly advise how to carry out numerical differentiation from a set of data points in *Mathematica*.

Comment: Are the $y_k$ exact, or do they have experimental error in them?

Comment: As to the `Import` error: probably the path name to your file is incorrect. Don't forget, on Windows, you need to escape the backslashes in a file name string with a backslash. A good trick is to copy the path string using the Insert/File path menu item. Additionally, "table" should be with uppercase T. You might want to read [this Import doc page](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/format/Table.html)

Comment: @J.M. no yk's are not exact they have experimental error in them

Comment: @Sjoerd.C.de Vries...Thanks for the advise. I am trying it.

Comment: Ah, then you'll have to do some smoothing, and you can't exactly use Markus's solution. Anyway, please include this **vital** piece of information into your question.

Comment: Since your points are evenly spaced and include some error you may use the Savitzky-Golay filter to find the smoothed second derivative. This is easy enough to accomplish in Mathematica. Here you ask two questions: one about the plot (is it only 1500 points? That should not take too long to plot; 15 million will be a different matter) and one about the derivative. If you split this into two questions I am sure you will get better answers.

Comment: @OleksandrR. Since 1500 points indeed shouldn't be a problem for ListPlot my guess was that the time-consuming part consists of entering the data as a literal argument to ListPlot. That's why he asked the question about Import.

Comment: @Sjoerd C.de Vries...thank you very much Sir, I tried the "Import" command as u said and it worked !! :) . I got rid of that tedious job of feeding my data one by one.

Answer (score 7):

There is a Fourier transform method [here](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2002/Feb/msg00379.html). Using the example from belisarius it might be done as below. Caveat: I do not guarantee I made no cut-and-paste errors. Your mileage may vary. Considerably.

```
(* sample data *)
g[x_] := x + 1/2 Sin[x] + RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[.2, .05]];

SeedRandom[1111];
xmax = 8*Pi;
nHalf = 750;
n = 2*nHalf;
xt = Table[i*xmax/n, {i, 0, n}]; (* the domain sampling points *)
t = Table[g[x], {x, 0., 8. Pi, xmax/n}];

(* Subtract beginning from end to get drift; we need to remove that to get something that is periodic-like. Probably should average the first few and last few points to get a better approximation to the drift. *)

range = t[[-1]] - t[[1]];

t2 = t - Range[Length[t]]*range/Length[t];

(* Smoothing magic...*)
ismooth = 10;

(* Get FT, multiply appropriately to get FT of derivative, then invert by IFT. last, add back the linear drift. *)

fourier = Fourier[t2];
freq1 = -2*Pi*I*
  Table[i*Exp[-(i/ismooth)^2], {i, 1, nHalf}]/(xmax);
freq2 = 
 2*Pi*I*Table[i*Exp[-(i/ismooth)^2], {i, 1, nHalf}]/(xmax);
freq = Join[{0}, freq1, Reverse[freq2]];
fourierd = fourier*freq; 
der = InverseFourier[fourierd] + range/xmax;

(* Pictures *)
ListPlot[Transpose[{xt, t}]]
```

[image]

```
(* Plot of samples minus drift *)
ListPlot[Transpose[{xt, t2}], PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.001]}]
```

[image]

```
(* approximated derivative *)

ListPlot[Transpose[{xt, der}], PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.001]}
```

[image]

(* We can get the second derivative similarly. Since we used a linearized approximated drift we need not add it back at the end.*)

```
freq1b = (-2*Pi*I)^2*
   Table[i^2*Exp[-(i/ismooth)^2], {i, 1, nHalf}]/xmax^2;
freq2b = (2*Pi*I)^2*
   Table[i^2*Exp[-(i/ismooth)^2], {i, 1, nHalf}]/xmax^2;
freqb = Join[{0}, freq1b, Reverse[freq2b]];
fourierd2 = fourier*freqb;
der2 = InverseFourier[fourierd2];

ListPlot[Transpose[{xt, der2}], PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.001]}]
```

[image]

I also tried this with

```
g2[x_] := Exp[x^(1/10)] - Exp[-x^2*Abs[Cos[x]]] + 
   RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[.2, .05]];
```

I got what I believe were tolerable results, although maybe not useful at the ends. No surprise, given that this is not so close to "periodic plus linear drift".

Comment: Thanks a lot for giving your time to write such a descriptive answer to my question. I will surely try this.

Comment: Nice answer! But could someone explain please, why the "freq" are calculated in two parts?

Comment: @Szczypawka My vague recollection is that it was to handle the way Fourier wraps frequencies-- one needs to reverse the second half.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Yeah, you are write. It seems to be a mathematical artifact of converting from Sin and Cos to Exp and losing physical meaning of frequency. Still, it's a very interesting question, but suprisingly it is not discussed here.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a way that combines two filters and a [numerical eighth order approximation to the derivatives](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6193702#6193702). Depending on your data, it may work pretty well.

Another (perhaps better) alternative is using [a Savitzky-Golay style filter](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2012/Feb/msg00036.html).

Some code:

```
(* Derivative Coeffs *)
ld = With[{m = 1, s = 8, n = 16}, CoefficientList[Normal[Series[x^s Log[x]^m, {x, 1, n}]], x]]
g[x_] := x + 1/2 Sin[x] +  RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[.2, .05]]; 
(*Our data*)
t = Table[g[x], {x, 0, 8 Pi, 8 Pi/1500}];
(*filtered data*)
tvf = TotalVariationFilter[t, 20, MaxIterations -> 100]
(* First derivative*)
fd = ListCorrelate[ld, MovingAverage[tvf, 30]];
(*second derivative*)
sd = MovingAverage[ListCorrelate[ld,TotalVariationFilter[fd, 20, MaxIterations -> 100]], 20];
GraphicsGrid[{ListPlot /@ {t, tvf}, ListPlot /@ {fd, sd}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Just for guidance, if you're using `CoefficientList[Normal[Series[x^s Log[x]^m, {x, 1, n}]], x]`: for a central difference construction, you can simplify this to `CoefficientList[Normal[Series[x^s Log[x]^m, {x, 1, 2 s}]], x]`; `m` is the order of the derivative, and `2 s + 1` is the number of points used. For more details, see [this article](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/S0036144596322507).

Answer (score 4):

Depending on the data, you may be able to use the built-in `DerivativeFilter` to locate the peak in the second derivative.

Create some noisy example data with a pronounced peak in the second derivative:

```
data = Table[
   1 - TriangleWave[x] + RandomReal[NormalDistribution[0, .05]], 
  {x, 0, 0.5, 0.5/1500.}];
```

Use a `DerivativeFilter` with a large value for the regularization parameter:

```
smoothedSecondDerivative = DerivativeFilter[data, {2}, 50.];
```

This produces a rather wide peak, but it may be good enough to locate the position of the peak. For data with a higher SNR you could use a smaller regularization parameter and obtain a narrower peak.

```
ListLinePlot[{data, 50000 smoothedSecondDerivative}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: I think [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4423) is rather relevant if the data look like this. The code is computationally intensive and will need some tweaking, but the algorithm is intended specifically for cases such as this.

Comment: @OleksandrR.,thanks for the link, that looks like a powerful method. Without seeing some example data from the OP it's hard to know what approach is best.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Interpolation` to create an `InterpolationFunction` and then perform the derivation on the interpolation function:

```
data = Table[{x, Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi, 0.01}];
fkt = Interpolation[data];
Plot[{fkt[x], fkt'[x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image]

The prime (fkt') gives you the first derivative. Alternatively you can use `D[fkt[x], x]`

Comment: Using interpolation of course assumes that the points do not have experimental error in them. Additionally, it should be noted that `Interpolation[]` by default yields a piecewise cubic function; to change the degree of the polynomial pieces used, change the setting of `InterpolationOrder`.

Comment: @ M.Roellig,Thanks for your advise. But, I don't know the functional dependence of my data points. I simply have a large set of data points which I want to plot. How to go about that? coz' writing the (xi,yi) points individually is too tedious.Thank you.

Comment: @ShrabantiDhar That is just an set of example data. Just use your data points (paris of x,y values instead).

Comment: @J.M. agreed, but without further knowldge of the posters data it is hard to be more specific. Of course some initial smoothing and hand-massaging of the data might be necessary.