# What does LinearSolve Preconditioner do?

Tags: equation-solving, matrix, linear-algebra

I have looked at a few places in order to find an answer to my question - specifically, I have looked at [this old Mathematica documentation page](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v5_2/Built-inFunctions/AdvancedDocumentation/LinearAlgebra/LinearAlgebraInMathematica/MatrixComputations/SolvingLinearSystems/AdvancedDocumentationLinearAlgebra3.1.5.html), at the Preconditioner option for NDSolve, as explained [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveIDAMethod.html), also at [this older question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4423/using-the-krylov-method-for-solve-speeding-up-a-sparsearray-calculation) and at [this unanswered post here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/82645/linearsolve-and-krylov-method-options), but I still don't understand what the Preconditioner option does. Does it multiply the matrix and the vector in the linear solve by something (or by its inverse)? How and from where does it take arguments? How can I specify a user-defined function and what should be the form of that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**TL;DR** Basically, a preconditioner is meant to speed up the convergence of iterative linear solvers. A preconditioner in Mathematica is the inverse of what is called preconditioner in numerical Mathematics.

---

The computational backend for `LinearSolve[A,b,Method->"Krylov" ]` is `` SparseArray`KrylovLinearSolve ``.

More or less,

```
SparseArray`KrylovLinearSolve[A,b, "Method" -> "BiCGSTAB", "Preconditioner" -> f]
```

should be equivalent to

```
LinearSolve[A,b, Method -> {
  "Krylov", 
  "Method" -> "BiCGSTAB", "Preconditioner" -> "ILU0"
  }]
```

However, calling `` SparseArray`KrylovLinearSolve `` directly is usually a bit faster because `LinearSolve` seems to have some overhead.

Other supported Krylov methods are `"ConjugateGradient"` (only for symmetric positive-definite matrices) and `"GMRES"`. See the documentation of `LinearSolve`, section Options, subsection Methods, subsubsection "Krylov".

You can use an arbitrary function `f` as preconditioner. Here an example for a built-in preconditioner (incomplete LU-factorization without fill-in):

```
precdata = SparseArray`SparseMatrixILU[A, "Method" -> "ILU0"]
f = x \[Function] SparseArray`SparseMatrixApplyILU[precdata, x]
```

Other accepted values for the option `"Method"` in `` SparseArray`SparseMatrixILU `` are `"ILUT"` and `"ILUTP"`.

Another example is this:

```
f = With[{invdiag = 1/Normal[Diagonal[A]]},
   x |-> invdiag x
   ];
```

It is the well-known [Jacobi preconditioner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preconditioner#Jacobi_(or_diagonal)_preconditioner)
-- or rather its inverse.

In constrast to the mathematical nomenclature, a preconditioner itself gets applied, not its inverse, in Mathematica. That's very plausible from an algorithmic point of view.

See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preconditioner#Jacobi_(or_diagonal)_preconditioner) and the standard literature about numerical linear equations for more information about what a preconditioner is. Basically, a preconditioner $f$ is meant to speed up the convergence of iterative linear solvers. Sloppily formulated, $f$ is a good preconditioner for the matrix $A$ if 1. $f(x)$ is easy to compute for each vector $x$ and 2. $A \,f(x)$ is close to $x$. So, a good preconditioner $f$ should best be almost an inverse of $A$ - but orders of magnitude faster than computing $A^{-1} x$ with direct methods.

Comment: I had a look at the page you have linked adn the LinearSolve documentation, before posting my question. 
What is x in your example? f = x \[Function] Evaluate[1/Diagonal[A] x]
Also you said "Using `SparseArray`KrylovLinearSolve`", but this is just a different linear solver, isn't it? How can I build preconditioners with it? I can't find any documentation on it.
And finally, if I understand correctly
"In constrast to the mathematical nomenclature, a preconditioner itself gets applied, not its inverse, in Mathematica", means I have to pass Mathematica the inverse of P (Wiki notation)

Comment: `x` is a certain vector that occurs in the iterative algorithms (some sort of residual). ``SparseArray`KrylovLinearSolve`` is the backend of `LinearSolve[A,b,Method -> "Krylov"]`. The only built-in precondtioners I know of are those generated by ``SparseArray`SparseMatrixILU``. And yes, there _is_ no documentation about it. "And finally...": You are correct.

Comment: Thank you! Can you give me an example how to use `SparseArray"`"KrylovLinearSolve` in order to build a preconditioner?

Comment: I've already given an example (it is ``SparseArray`SparseMatrixApplyILU`` that creates data for a preconditioner).

Comment: Oh, I see, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: Sorry for all the questions. In your example - 
f = x \[Function] Evaluate[1/Diagonal[A] x] - the preconditioner is a vector, right? Shouldn't it be a matrix?

Comment: The preconditioners in Mathematica are meant to be _actions_ on a vector. This particular function is a fast version of `f = x \[Function] Evaluate[DiagonalMatrix[1/Diagonal[A]].x]`... ;)